# Enable sorting by __str__ column in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a django project with a model that looks like:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    #some other stuff
    owner = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.owner.name
    __unicode__.admin_order_field = 'owner__last_name'
```

My model admin looks something like:

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['-last_modified']
    list_display = ['__unicode__', 'last_modified']
```

I would like for the admin to be sorted by `last_modified` by default (as it is now) but to be able to sort alphabetically by clicking on the top of the first column of the list display. I tried to add the `__unicode__.admin_order_field` line as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), but that doesn't seem to have made any difference. Is what I want possible? If not why not?

Comment: Are you using Python 2? I'm not sure whether `admin_order_field` works with double underscores to span foreign keys. Have you tried `__unicode__.admin_order_field='owner'` (it won't give you the result you want, but it will show you if the problem is `'owner__last_name'`.

Comment: Hi @Alasdair, thanks for response. I am using python 2.7 yes. I actually already have another method (that I left out to simplify problem) 'date_joined` with admin_order_field that spans the owner relationship - `date_joined.admin_order_field='owner__date_joined'`. That works fine so I don't think that is the problem. Also if I remove `'__unicode__'` from the list I can sort fine by any of the other fields.

Comment: Looks like you may possible need to use http://django-admin-sortable.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html

Answer (score 3):

You can only sort fields in the django admin interface if they are fields on your model or if they are fields you custom annotate in the `get_queryset` method of your ModelAdmin class--essentially fields created at the DB level. However, assuming you are deriving your `__unicode__` or `__str__` method from some fields on your model (and you are--from `owner.name`) you should be able to reference those fields and make the column sortable like so (though you could use this method to make the **unicode** field sortable on any model attribute you'd like):

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def sortable_unicode(self, obj):
        return obj.__unicode__()

    sortable_unicode.short_description = 'Owner Name'
    sortable_unicode.admin_order_field = 'owner__last_name'

    ordering = ['-last_modified']
    list_display = ['sortable_unicode', 'last_modified']
```

Though I do find it a bit strange that you will be displaying the owner's `name` but sorting on `last_name`. This might be a bit puzzling when you wonder why your sort order doesn't match the displayed `name` in the admin interface.