# Sort django admin column by __str__ method

Tags: python, django

I have a Folder model and I want to display the columns in the admin page ordered alphabetically following the __str__ method.

I looked over several similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760082/django-admin-how-to-sort-column-by-custom-method), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168475/django-admin-how-to-sort-by-one-of-the-custom-list-display-fields-that-has-no-d) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889601/enable-sorting-by-str-column-in-django-admin), but didn't manage to really understand the answers, or at least enough to adapt them to my problem (even though I've been trying for quite some time).

**Here is my Folder class, with the str method I want to sort with :**

```
class Folder(models.Model):
    folder_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent_folder = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.parent_folder:
            return f'{self.parent_folder}/{self.folder_name}'
        else:
            return self.folder_name
```

**And my FolderAdmin class :**

```
class FolderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ('str',) #I want it to do like that but don't know how to do it
    
    fieldsets = [
        (None,            {'fields': ['folder_name']}),
        ('Parent Folder', {'fields': ['parent_folder']}),
    ]
    
    list_display = ('folder_name', '__str__')
```

I feel dumb for not understanding a question already answered multiple times but if you could help me understand it I'd be grateful.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Why not simply do `ordering = ('parent_folder', 'folder_name')`? That does exactly what you want right? First order on parent folder (if any), then on folder_name.

Comment: That seems to work, thank you so much ! That was so simple, it's frustrating...